# VBA Class Module to navigate Between ActiveX Controls on a Sheet by pressing TAB key

Tags: excel, vba, activex, keyevent

**Trying to Accomplish:** There are a few TextBoxes and ComboBoxes (ActiveX Controls) arranged in order on an Excel worksheet (Sheet1) like a UserForm. I would like to navigate between these controls by tabbing (pressing TAB key).

**Partial Success:** I am able to navigate between TextBoxes using the method and codes shown below. However I have no idea how to go about it when ComboBoxes are also involved.

**PLEASE NOTE:** All these controls are grouped and it has to remain so.

**How I was able to navigate between TextBoxes:**

*Inserted a Class Module by name ClsEventTxtBx and added the following codes*

```
    Public WithEvents CTxtBx As MSForms.TextBox

    Private Sub CTxtBx_KeyDown(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal Shift As Integer)
        If KeyCode = vbKeyTab Then
          JumpingToNextTextBox CTxtBx
        End If
    End Sub
```

*Inserted a Standard Module and added the Subroutine JumpingToNextTextBox*

```
    Sub JumpingToNextTextBox(ActiveCtl As MSForms.TextBox)

    Dim shp As Shape, oleshp As Shape, i As Integer, ctlArr()

    For Each shp In Sheet1.Shapes
       If shp.Type = msoGroup Then
           For Each oleshp In shp.GroupItems
               If TypeName(oleshp.OLEFormat.Object.Object) = "TextBox" Then
                  i = i + 1
                  ReDim Preserve ctlArr(1 To i)
                  ctlArr(i) = oleshp.OLEFormat.Object.Name
               End If
           Next oleshp
      End If
    Next shp

    i = 0

    For i = LBound(ctlArr) To UBound(ctlArr)
        If ActiveCtl.Name = ctlArr(i) Then
            If Not i = UBound(ctlArr) Then
                Sheet1.OLEObjects(ctlArr(i + 1)).Activate
            Else
                Sheet1.OLEObjects(ctlArr(1)).Activate
            End If
        End If
    Next I

   End Sub
```

Added the following codes in ThisWorkBook

```
    Dim ctlArr() As New ClsEventTxtBx

    Private Sub Workbook_Open()
       Dim i As Integer, shp As Shape, oleshp As Shape, oleArr(), oleObject As oleObject
       Dim oleColl As New Collection

    
       For Each shp In Sheet1.Shapes

           If shp.Type = msoGroup Then
               For Each oleshp In shp.GroupItems
                   If oleshp.Type = msoOLEControlObject Then
                       If TypeName(oleshp.OLEFormat.Object.Object) = "TextBox" Then
                           i = i + 1
                           ReDim Preserve ctlArr(1 To i)
                           Set ctlArr(i).CTxtBx = oleshp.OLEFormat.Object.Object
                       End If
                   End If
               Next oleshp
           End If

       Next shp
    End Sub
```

Comment: "arranged in order" is relative in the Excel context. Their order is the one of their creation. Now, your code put in an array only the text boxes name and then jump from one to the other, according to their creation order. What would you like accomplishing? To also jump between each existing combo boxes, if Tab key is pressed when the cursor is inside one of them? To jump to such a combo box when the cursor is in the last (created) text box, or what?

Comment: Let us assume the controls are in the following order (I am okay with the order of creation). TextBox1, TextBox2, ComboBox1, TextBox3, ComboBox 2. If I am in ComboBox1 and press TAB, cursor should move to TextBox3. Whichever is the next in sequence should get activated. If the cursor is in ComboBox2, pressing tab should move cursor to TextBox1.

Comment: Then, you must create another class to trigger the `KeyDown` (or `KeyUp`) event of a combo box. Both events (of the text boxes and combo boxes, too) should call a common event, let us say `JumpingToNextControl`. Then, in the `Workbook_Open` event place a similar piece of code to allocate the event to all combo boxes. The sub to jump between controls will use `If TypeName(...)= "TextBox" Or TypeName(...)= "ComboBox"` and the same philosophy. Now, pressing Tab in any of such controls should jump to the next (created) one...

Comment: Let me try that. Meanwhile, is there a way I could create a single class to trigger the event for an OLEObject and then use  `JumpingToNextControl` to allocate the event to all OLEObjects?

Comment: I am afraid that you cannot. The class you use to allocate events is a kind of wrapper. I mean, it can handle only **existing events** for the declared object  (`As MSForms.TextBox` in your case) class. Since an `OLEObject` class itself does not expose any event you cannot simple create (a general) one...

Comment: You can optimize your code creating the `ctlArr()` as a `Global` variable at a standard module level and fill it using `Worksheet_Activate` event. It is not necessary to fill it each time you run `JumpingToNextTextBox`. If you add new controls, it should be enough to deactivate - activate the sheet. Only once...